# Derivation of path integral formula in the case of fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

While deriving the path integral formula from the formula known for transition amplitudes in the Schrodinger formalism, one discretises time and inserts a complete set of basis states for position and momentum at each infinitesimal time interval and then integrates over phase space. For a quantum field, an arbitrary state may be expanded in terms of a one particle state, two particle state and so on, so inserting the identity operator will be of the form,

$$
I = |0)(0| + \int \mathrm{d}p |p)(p| + ...
$$

So how does one derive the path integral formula in QFT like one would do in quantum mechanics from the Schrodinger picture?

Comment: You have to expand in the eigenbasis of $\pi(x)$, not in that of $P^\mu$. Therefore, your $I=|0\rangle\langle0|+\cdots$ is irrelevant here. In any case, if your question is how to derive the PI formula in QFT, then the answer is: as it is done in every book on the subject. What else do you want to know?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thank you for the clarification. Incidentally in Peskin and Schroeder, the authors do not derive the formula separately for the case of fields. They simply derive it for the case of a non-relativistic particle in one dimension and state that it must hold for a quantum field theory as well.

Comment: you can find the QFT derivation in Weinberg's book, chapter 9.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks a lot. I'll look it up.